# combine multiple columns in excel into one column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
    Column1  Column2      
 0    a        jack       
 1    a        peter      
 2    b        anna     
 3    c        rose                     
 4    c        pupp
```

What I want to do now is getting a new dataframe containing Column1 and column 2, column 2 should get   if row1 == row2 then print values of column 2 , the output should be like this

```
 Column1    Column2

0   a      jack,peter    
1   b      anna
2   c      rose,pupp
```

How could I best approach this issue? Any advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `join`:

```
df = df.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
print (df)
  Column1      Column2
0       a  jack, peter
1       b         anna
2       c   rose, pupp
```